# VSCode ESLint Prettier formatOnSave being undone

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint, prettier

I'm was trying to resolve some cross-platform issues in our linting (in my case a line-ending issue between Windows and IOs platforms).

Line ending problem is resolved (had to do with a `files.eol` setting) but when I save my file, some linting is getting reverted, like so

[image: save being reverted]

below are my workspace and linting config. What is fighting back at me here?

`.eslintrc.js`

```js
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  extends: '@react-native-community',
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  plugins: ['@typescript-eslint', 'unused-imports'],
  overrides: [
    {
      files: ['*.ts', '*.tsx', '*.js'],
      rules: {
        'prettier/prettier': [
          'error',
          {
            endOfLine: 'auto',
          },
        ],
        '@typescript-eslint/no-shadow': ['error'],
        'no-shadow': 'off',
        'no-undef': 'off',
        'no-console': 'warn',
        '@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars': 'off',
        'react/no-unstable-nested-components': ['warn', {allowAsProps: true}],
        'unused-imports/no-unused-imports': 'error',
        'unused-imports/no-unused-vars': [
          'warn',
          {
            vars: 'all',
            varsIgnorePattern: '^_',
            args: 'after-used',
            argsIgnorePattern: '^_',
          },
        ],
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

`.prettierrc.js`

```js
module.exports = {
  bracketSpacing: false,
  bracketSameLine: true,
  singleQuote: true,
  trailingComma: "all",
  arrowParens: "avoid",
};
```

`myproject.code-workspace`

```json
{
  "folders": [
    {
      "path": "."
    }
  ],
  "settings": {
    "compilerOptions": {
      "baseUrl": "",
      "paths": {
        "lib/*": ["src/lib/*"]
      }
    },
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.rulers": [],
    "editor.tabSize": 2,
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
      "source.fixAll.eslint": true
    },
    "tailwindCSS.experimental.classRegex": [
      "tw`([^`]*)", // tw`...`
      "tw=\"([^\"]*)", // <div tw="..." />
      "tw={\"([^\"}]*)", // <div tw={"..."} />
      "tw\\.\\w+`([^`]*)", // tw.xxx`...`
      "tw\\(.*?\\)`([^`]*)" // tw(Component)`...`
    ],
    "eslint.format.enable": true,
    "eslint.validate": [
      "javascript",
      "javascriptreact",
      "typescript",
      "typescriptreact"
    ],
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
    "[javascript]": {
      "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    }
  },
  "extensions": {
    "recommendations": [
      "mikestead.dotenv",
      "dsznajder.es7-react-js-snippets",
      "eamodio.gitlens",
      "dbaeumer.vscode-eslint",
      "austenc.tailwind-docs",
      "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
      "adpyke.codesnap"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok problem was the workspace settings `editor.formatOnSave` and the `editor.codeActionsOnSave`.

My formatting is handled by the linting so I didn't need the VSCode formatter fighting with the linting.